# Custom Policies: Application has not been granted consent and is unable to be used for local accounts

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create a custom policy for my app in Azure B2C. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom) tutorial that configures a basic custom policy and uploads the necessary policy xml files.  At the end when I navigate to the the policy to test it out and enter a user id / password I get the following error:

The application with identifier '...' has not been granted consent and is unable to be used for local accounts.

In order to fix this I have been searching for how to grant consent. I have tried navigating to the Azure Ad blade -> Enterprise applications -> My App. Under the Security menu on the left hand side, there is the menu option "Permissions" but it is disabled.

How do I enable this option?

How do I grant consent for my policy to be used for local accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consent should be granted when [the ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework application is created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#register-the-proxyidentityexperienceframework-application) (see step 9).

Comment: I must have skipped part of that step. You are a lifesaver!

Comment: Chris, would you happen to have documentation on the definitions of the xml fields in a custom policy (TrustedFrameworkBase.xml)? I'm trying to define the JwtIssuer property refresh_token_lifetime_secs and I think it is an old one not being used.

Comment: Hi @afriedman111. You can find information about the JWT issuer at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/jwt-issuer-technical-profile).